# How to add custom Dashlets

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm a SugarCRM Professional (v10.2) admin with the instance hosted on SugarCloud.

I want to add some additional Dashlets to the instance that aren't available out of the box.

I've created a basic 'Hello World' Dashlet and have the PHP, JS, and HBS saved locally right now.

How do I get the PHP, JS and HBS into my SugarCloud instance?

I have tried typing the following into browser:

```
    custom/clients/base/views/
```

But I cannot access this directory.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For cloud versions a package must be build

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_9.0/Cookbook/Module_Loadable_Packages/

Here you can read how to build a package and copy your files